# How to make class member NOT shared between threads (2 browser sessions)

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, thread-safety, class-members

I'm implementing a web application. 
I send 1 ajax request to call 1000+ api requests and save the result into a class member when it's finished.

Meanwhile, I send another async request to poll if the request was finished then return result to browser.

The problem is that class member is shared between two browsers when there are two users send the request at the same time.

The question is how to make class member NOT shared between two tabs of e.g. chrome browser.

NOTE: I'm using springboot java for the implementation.

```
Sample code
@RestController
public class RestController{
private CompletableFuture< CopyOnWriteArrayList< Object > > results; 
@Autowired
private RestService restService;

@PostMapping( "/sendRequest" )
private void sendRequests(....){
  results = restService.sendRequests(..); // save result to class member
}

@GetMapping("/pollResult")
private JsonResponse pollResult(..){
  //check if result is not null (async request)

return response;
}


}
```

a.html

```
ajax
{
url // send api request

}


another Ajax call to poll result every 5 seconds
```

Comment: you should add some code showing what you have done. We cannot help you with just a description

Comment: Use singleton instances of the classes, so that each request will have its own copy of the class instance.

Comment: Queue the request on the server side. Return an id to the caller. When the work is done stash the result with the id as the key on the server. Have the caller poll the server with the id. Time out old responses to avoid problems when people go away. This will work for a single web server. If you scale up with a load-balancer then it's time to start thinking about where you record the work request/response.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I have added some code... thanks for reminding.

Comment: @NullPointerException spring controller itself is already singleton... please suggest.

Comment: My Bad, not singleton but request scoped, what I meat to say was you can use request scope for the classed that needs to hold the data 
e.g.
`@Scope(value = "request")`

Comment: @NullPointerException I tried this but in the async request to poll the result (my sample code) can't get the result. It always get results = null. I would like the another request to poll result to be able to get the result that was saved in the "results" class member.

Comment: @AndyBrown i would write this as answer, it provides a good solution (and is actually an answer to the question).

Comment: @dunni I was trying to implement as per Andy Brown's suggestion, but the problem is that another thread is changing the results value of the first thread. So I cannot save the results with its respective requestId. Also, I cannot wait for the results to be done as it's too long and the server has connection timeout for 1 minute. Please suggest.

Comment: You don't have to wait. Just return the request id immediately. And why doesn't it work that the 2nd thread can save the result? Of course you have to pass the request id through to the 2nd thread when you create it.

Comment: Yes, no waiting. Generate a UUID for the id and return it immediately. The queue should be a concurrent bounded queue serviced by a ThreadPoolExecutor (or similar). When the Runnable servicing the request completes, place the result in a ConcurrentMap with the UUID as the key.

Comment: @AndyBrown thanks!! this solution works perfectly